# Difference in css outcome between static and jinja2 html

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I am using `Flask` and therefore `Jinja2` to dynamically create a web page.

When I use the `render_template` function the resulting web pages pick up my css styles normally and do as I expect with some strange exceptions.

For example, the following css and html code is working 100% as intended:

CSS:

```css
.intro {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #455934;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<p class ='intro'>
    Hello
</p>
```

However when using a ``Jinja2``` template:

```html
<p class ='intro'>
    {{title}}
</p>
```

The css style for this class is ignored.

This is not true for any other styles in the same css file and template, for reference the whole template looks like this and the styles for div containers, background, etc. work as intended:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='gemuese_style.css') }}">
        <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="inner">
                    <p class ='intro'>
                        {{title}}
                    </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>{{result}}</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Some testing has shown me that the style seems to work depending on the variable jinja renders. The template is rendered based on the output of different functions who generally return a list of a string and another list. The string is then used to fill in the {{title}} part where the css is failing.

For some functions it does work but I am not sure why because there is no difference in the return format.

Edit2:

Look at the difference between [This rendered template](http://flaskrtest3.herokuapp.com/gemuese/suggestion)  and [this one.](http://flaskrtest3.herokuapp.com/gemuese/getrecipe)

Comment: Which rules in particular are not being applied? Have you inspected the element in devtools? Is there a problem in loading the stylesheet? Lots of things you can look at yourself which we can't really answer for you.

Comment: Just saw the edit. I think you need to share the actual HTML that's output. Could the `title` property perhaps contain some HTML content (it seems Jinja doesn't escape HTML by default) that may be invalid and cause the browser to close the `p` tag before you are expecting? As I said, this can only really be solved by looking at what HTML you're actually getting.

Comment: The app is here: http://flaskrtest3.herokuapp.com/gemuese/suggestion notice the difference to http://flaskrtest3.herokuapp.com/gemuese/getrecipe

Comment: @RobinZigmond  As to styles not applied it is everything in the intro headline as seen above, so padding/font/size. Other style elements like list format, background work in all cases.

Comment: thanks for the link - that makes it clear that this isn't a CSS issue. Look at the generated HTML, and you'll see that the `<p class="intro">` simply isn't there at all. This means it can't have been generated from that particular template. Perhaps there is an error in your backend code, eg in the routes?

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks you are 100% right, my return_template function used two different templates based on return-type (string vs. list), I was expecting all functions to return as string but this was not the case (some returned as [string], which is obviously a list). If you want to put this up as an answer I mark it as solved.

Comment: I don't feel able to post an answer because I didn't come up with anything, and indeed it was impossible for anyone seeing your question to be able to answer it, because the actual cause was in code you didn't share. I am happy to have helped point you in the right direction to enable you to figure out the cause yourself. I will vote to close the question though because it will not likely be of any help to others in the future.